# update inner join - mysql

Tags: mysql

I've used the following query quite often, but with this new db, it's giving me an error of incorrect usage, can you guys take a look and let me know what i'm doing wrong?

```
UPDATE `master` maa
INNER JOIN `cdr` ca ON `maa`.numbers=ca.target
SET `maa`.monthly_mins=ca.secs
ORDER BY ca.secs;
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: `ORDER BY` is not needed.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try this one? This is what documentation says for multi table update though.

> For the multiple-table syntax, UPDATE updates rows in each table named in table_references that satisfy the conditions. In this case, ORDER BY and LIMIT cannot be used.

Then again you are only updating one table. By just removing order by clause will help.

```
UPDATE `master` maa 
INNER JOIN `cdr` ca 
ON `maa`.numbers=ca.target 
SET `maa`.monthly_mins=ca.secs;
```

Comment: To be able to use "ORDER BY", you could do a subquery where you SELECT all the datas in the order you want

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
   UPDATE `master` maa
   INNER JOIN `cdr` ca 
   ON `maa`.numbers=ca.target
   SET `maa`.monthly_mins=ca.secs
```